# jackson fasterxml multiple elements with the same name not aligned together

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, fasterxml

```
<A>
        
        <Ser name="cluster1" localroot="search" branch="feature>
        </Ser>
        <PR localroot="search" msg="Merge the pr."/>

        <Ser name="cluster2" localroot="clone" branch="change-fix>
        </Ser>
        <PR localroot="clone" msg="Merge the pr."/>
</A>
```

Trying to read the same using XmlMapper.readValue()
but It is just reading the last value of both  &  not the list.

Note: this works well when Xml is:

```
    <A>
            <Ser name="cluster1" localroot="search" branch="feature>
            </Ser>
            
            <Ser name="cluster2" localroot="clone" branch="change-fix>
            </Ser>
            <PR localroot="search" msg="Merge the pr."/>
            <PR localroot="clone" msg="Merge the pr."/>
            
    </A>
```

Code is: `

```
public class A {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Ser")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    List<Ser> ser;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="PR")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    List<PR> pR;
    
    \\getters
     \\Setters
    
}
```

`

For Ser:

```
public class Ser {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true,localName="name")
    String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true,localName="branch")
    String branch;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true,localName="localroot")
    String localroot;

\\getter & setters

}
```

Similar code for PR:

```
public class PR {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true,localName="msg")
    String msg;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true,localName="localroot")
    String localroot;

\\getter & setters

}
```

Code where reading the file having XML:

```
public ServiceImpl{
\\hiding other part.

A obj = xmlMapper.readValue(new File(path), A.class);

}
```

Tried with the latest version as well for jackson-dataformat-xml.
Nothing working.

This question is different as here issue is not of wrapping xml.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.